# 404 not working properly

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I've built an asp.net website which runs on IIS 7.5. in the web.config we use custom errors for a 404 page.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/oops.aspx?type=error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="oops.aspx?type=404"/>
</customErrors>
```

When we use an url like www.ourdomain.com/stackoverflow , we get redirected to the 404 page that we set in our customerrors part of the web.config. when we go to www.ourdomain.com/stackoverflow.aspx we get a blank page and not the 404 page (as this page doesn't exist). Also the page gets a status code 200 (for OK).

Comment: Have you done some URL rewrites along ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your URL rewrite method if it's redirecting properly to the path of your Error page...as you are getting Status code 200 which indicates your processing has completed. So you should check your URL rewrite method for errors...